# Use parts of Main dataframe without actually splitting it into small dataframes pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe which has around 17000 rows

i want to create small dataframes from this for my use, such that
each dataframe has 6000 rows.

therefore

```
df1 = 6000 rows
df2 = 6000 rows
df3 = 5000 rows (remaining rows)
```

this can be done by slicing my main_df

But making this small df's will consume my ram,
is there any way of using it directly from the main_df

as slices without actually creating small dataframes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create `MultiIndex` with `RangeIndex` and floor division:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(100,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
#change 20 to 6000 in real data
df.index = [pd.RangeIndex(len(df.index)) // 20, df.index]
print (df)
      A  B  C  D  E
0 0   8  8  3  7  7
  1   0  4  2  5  2
  2   2  2  1  0  8
  3   4  0  9  6  2
  4   4  1  5  3  4
  5   4  3  7  1  1
  6   7  7  0  2  9
  7   9  3  2  5  8
  8   1  0  7  6  2
  9   0  8  2  5  1
  10  8  1  5  4  2
  11  8  3  5  0  9
  12  3  6  3  4  7
  13  6  3  9  0  4
  14  4  5  7  6  6
  15  2  4  2  7  1
  16  6  6  0  7  2
  17  3  5  4  2  4
  18  3  7  9  0  0
  19  5  9  6  6  5
1 20  6  4  7  3  9
  21  2  3  8  7  1
  22  5  9  3  0  6
  ...
  ...
```

And then select by [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
print (df.xs(0, axis=0, level=0))

    A  B  C  D  E
0   8  8  3  7  7
1   0  4  2  5  2
2   2  2  1  0  8
3   4  0  9  6  2
4   4  1  5  3  4
5   4  3  7  1  1
6   7  7  0  2  9
7   9  3  2  5  8
8   1  0  7  6  2
9   0  8  2  5  1
10  8  1  5  4  2
11  8  3  5  0  9
12  3  6  3  4  7
13  6  3  9  0  4
14  4  5  7  6  6
15  2  4  2  7  1
16  6  6  0  7  2
17  3  5  4  2  4
18  3  7  9  0  0
19  5  9  6  6  5
```

Comment: ! you're a savior! Working great.  Just in case if i wanted to actually create smaller dataframes,(df1,df2..) depending on my chunksize of 6000, is there a optimal way of doing it?

Comment: i tried this `for g, tdf in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 6000):
    print(tdf.shape)`  but it's only printing shape of my df

Comment: Do you think `print(tdf)` instead `print(tdf.shape)` ?

Comment: Hmmm, I think one optimal is `dict` of `dataframes` - `d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 6000)))
print(d[0])`

Comment: printing tdf will give me output, instead of that can i save the slices as df1,df2,... in the for loop itself

Comment: Hmmm, if need create only a few dataframes then is possible use `df1=df.iloc[:6000], 
df2=df.iloc[6000:12000], df3=df.iloc[12000:]`. But for general solution need dict of dataframes.

Comment: sir can you please take a look at this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44131306/read-data-from-jsons-and-save-it-into-different-df-based-on-condition-pandas

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign slice ranges and use these to slice the orig df using `iloc` and passing these slice ranges:

```
In[53]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3), columns=list('abs'))
df

Out[53]: 
          a         b         s
0  0.487646  1.925704 -1.249352
1 -0.276991 -0.077153 -0.318227
2  2.030931 -0.301918  0.467074
3 -0.059828  1.965713 -1.284751
4 -1.022199  0.825156  1.582900
5  1.022663  0.204184  0.644900
6 -2.398288  0.175664 -0.808225
7 -0.600876 -1.359850  0.817557
8  0.039713  0.077957  0.167178
9  0.051465 -1.499899  2.051932
```

Now just assign slice ranges to your variables and pass these to `iloc`:

```
In[55]:
df1 = slice(0,3)
df2 = slice(3,6)
df3 = slice(6,df.shape[0])
print(df.iloc[df1])
print(df.iloc[df2])
print(df.iloc[df3])

          a         b         s
0  0.487646  1.925704 -1.249352
1 -0.276991 -0.077153 -0.318227
2  2.030931 -0.301918  0.467074

          a         b         s
3 -0.059828  1.965713 -1.284751
4 -1.022199  0.825156  1.582900
5  1.022663  0.204184  0.644900

          a         b         s
6 -2.398288  0.175664 -0.808225
7 -0.600876 -1.359850  0.817557
8  0.039713  0.077957  0.167178
9  0.051465 -1.499899  2.051932
```